# Android - issue with adding a polyline to map

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to add lines on google map in the following order, lines from "bg" then lines from "ln"

```
        for (PolylineOptions o : bg) {
            map.addPolyline(o);
        }

        for (PolylineOptions o : ln) {
            map.addPolyline(o);
        }
```

In fact sometimes, if i run this code, GoogleMap draws lines from "bg" above lines from "ln".
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the z-index of a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions.html#public-methods):

```
polylineOptions.zIndex(1f);
```

This should work in your case

```
for (PolylineOptions o : bg) {
    map.addPolyline(o);
}

for (PolylineOptions o : ln) {
    map.addPolyline(o.zIndex(1f));
}
```